# Compile PHP with cURL fail

Tags: php, linux, curl, compilation

I am manually compiling PHP (7.0.7) and cURL (7.49.1) on Ubuntu. The following error is seen during PHP compilation:

```
checking for cURL support... yes
checking for cURL 7.10.5 or greater... libcurl 7.49.1
checking for SSL support in libcurl... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for openssl support in libcurl... no
checking for gnutls support in libcurl... no
checking for curl_easy_perform in -lcurl... no
configure: error: There is something wrong. Please check config.log for more information.
```

Curl configuration:

```
./configure --prefix="${INSTALL_PATH}/curl"              \
            --with-openssl="${INSTALL_PATH}/openssl/"
```

PHP configuration

```
./configure --prefix="${INSTALL_PATH}/php"              \
                --with-apxs2="${INSTALL_PATH}/httpd/bin/apxs"   \
                --with-libxml-dir="${INSTALL_PATH}/libxml2"     \
                --with-gettext                                  \
                ${openldap_lib_option}                  \
                --with-openssl="${INSTALL_PATH}/openssl/" \
                --with-curl="${INSTALL_PATH}/curl/"
```

Appreciate any input. Do I need to get any extra package?
If compile PHP without cURL support, everything is fine.

The full config.log file is [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=51C2CF5E6538E8FB%21901). There is a bunch of "undefined reference" of OpenSSL stuff in the config.log. But I don't think they are the cause of the error as the same "undefined reference" happens for gnutls test and openssl test of libcurl as well. But it is a strange though as I have added OpenSSL (1.0.2g) in the package but still seeing "checking for openssl support in libcurl... no"..

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 amd64 to compile now. But soon will use 14.04/16.04 x86/amd64 to compile as well.

Comment: What is in config.log?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu is it about ? Like Ubuntu 14.04 - amd64, etc. -

Comment: @Kund Oh, I never know Ubuntu version matters. Is it because of the compiler? as I am not using any of the OS packages, I build all the packages myself... I am building it on Ubuntu 12.04 amd64 now. But I would also need to build it on Ubuntu 14.04/16.04 x86/amd64 soon.

Answer (score 5):

I just compiled PHP 7.0.8 on Debian 8 with `curl` and `openssl` support.

And here are dependencies which I installed to avoid compilation errors:

```
apt-get install libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev pkg-config
```

Plus, my `./configure` options in this section are next:

```
--with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
--with-openssl=/usr \
--with-curl \
```

Here is related topic on bugs.php.net:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69510

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install -y libbz2-dev sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libjpeg-dev libonig-dev libreadline-dev libtidy-dev libxslt-dev libzip-dev
```

Comment: Please, consider adding a short explanation of the command and explaining the reasons why this should work. We want to help OP to solve the problem but, considering this question is almost 6 years old, your answer may be more valuable for searchers.